# Symfony form's i18n and add_empty

Tags: symfony1

I have this widget:

```
$this->setWidget('slug', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' 
=> 'MyTable', 'method' => 'myMethod', 'key_method' => 'myMethod', 
'add_empty' => 'Select option')));
```

Ok, what should I do to translate the "Select option"?

I can't use the __() helper inside the form, and adding that string 
into my XLIFF file doesn't translate it automatically.

If it can't be done, what workaround should I implement? I can't find 
any way, and neither can't find any tip in the official documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have solved it:

```
$translated_text = $this->widgetSchema->getFormFormatter()->translate('String to translate');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper inside form, try this:

```
public function setup()
{
  sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers(array('I18n'));

  $this->setWidget('slug', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' 
    => 'MyTable', 'method' => 'myMethod', 'key_method' => 'myMethod', 
    'add_empty' => __('Select option'))); 
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is a very ugly solution and will not work in tests. Read [Why sfContext::getInstance() Is Bad](http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/).